# "8 Dice arranged as a Cube" Face-Sum Problem

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, dice

I found this [here](http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/dice.htm):

> **Sum Problem**
>
> Given eight dice. Build a $2\times 2\times2$ cube, so that the sum of the points on each side is the same.
>
> $\hskip2.7in$[image]
>
> Here is one of  20 736 solutions with the sum 14.
>   You find more at the German magazine "Bild der Wissenschaft 3-1980".

Now I have three (**Question 1 moved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/154451/19341)**) questions:

1. <s>Is $14$ the only possible face sum? At least, in the example given, it seems to related to the fact, that on every face two dice-pairs show up, having $n$ and $7-n$ [pips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28counting%29#Dice). Is this necessary? Sufficient it is...</s>
2. How do they get $20736$? This is the dimension of the related group and factors to $2^8\times 3^4$, the number of group elements, right?

   > i. I can get $2^3$, by the following: In the example given, you can split along the $xy$ ($yz,zx$) plane and then interchange the $2$ blocks of $4$ dice. Wlog, mirroring at $xy$ commutes with $yz$ (both just invert the $z$ resp. $x$ coordinate, right), so we get $2^3$ group lements. $$ $$
   >   ii. The factor $3$ looks related to rotations throught the diagonals. But without my role playing set at hand, I can't work that out. $$ $$
   >   iii. Would rolling the overall die around an axis also count, since back and front always shows a "rotated" pattern? This would give six $90^\circ$-rotations and three $180^\circ$-rotations, $9=3^2$ in total. 
   >   $$ \\ $$
   >   Where do the missing $2^5\times 3^2$ come from?
3. Is the reference given, online available?

**EDIT**

And to not make
tehshrike [sad
again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100615/given-a-die-what-is-the-probability-that-the-second-roll-of-a-die-will-be-less#comment237353_100615),
here's the special question for $D4$:

What face sum is possible, *so that the sum of the points on each side
is the same*, when you pile up 4 D4's to a pyramid (plus the octahedron mentioned by Henning) and how many representations, would such a pyramid
have?

Thanks

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/154451/19341, splitted due to request here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/229592/19341

Comment: The point is, you really should ask one question per question.

Comment: For the bonus question "(ok, 5 in the center for stability)", note that if you pile up four tetrahedra to form a larger tetrahedron, the open space in the middle is _not_ in the shape of a tetrahedron, but is an octahedron. So putting a fifth tetrahedron in the middle is not going to stabilize the construction appreciably.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks +1 for the correct stabilizer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your reference request:

The site of the magazine offers many of their articles online starting from 1997, so you cannot obtain the 1980 edition online (although you can likely buy a used print version).

Most good libraries in German-speaking countries do have this magazine, so, depending on your country, you could go directly go to the library, try to get an inter-library loan or contact friends in German-speaking countries to scan the appropriate pages for you.

Of course, the article will be in German.